# Quand et comment sont apparus les verbes défectifs ?

Tags: conjugaison, évolution, verbes-défectifs

Les verbes défectifs sont des verbes dont la conjugaison est incomplète, soit qu'ils ne s'emploient pas à toutes les personnes (*[falloir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aConjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/falloir)*), soit qu'ils ne s'emploient pas à tous les temps (*[gésir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aConjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/g%C3%A9sir)* et *[traire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aConjugaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais/traire)* par exemple).

Mes questions (liées) sont donc :

- Quand et comment la défectuosité de ces verbes a-t-elle été figée ?
- Est-ce l'usage qui s'est perdu progressivement, ou bien ces verbes ont-ils toujours eu une conjugaison restreinte ? (Et l'ont-ils emprunté à une autre langue ?)
- Enfin, quand a été figée la conjugaison que nous connaissons ? Est-ce un phénomène homogène dans le temps et dans l'espace ?

Comment: @Stéphane: merci pour les corrections, “s'employent” m'a faire rire parce que je connais ce tic de langage, mais je ne croyais pas l'avoir, et surtout pas à l'écrit !

Comment: Peut-on dire que la conjugaison est figée ? Par exemple n'assiste-t-on pas à un changement de la première personne du pluriel de tous les verbes (nous aimons -> on aime), à un changement de l'impératif du verbe s'asseoir (Assis-toi !), à des changements à la troisième personne du pluriel (Ils voyent, ils croyent, ils s'employent, etc.) ? Par définition, la langue écrite correcte est à peu près figée depuis la dernière réforme/codification orthographique qui « a pris » mais l'évolution de la langue parlée est sans doute un processus continu.

Comment: Merci pour toutes ces informations, cependant, je ne trouve nulle mention de l'origine de ces verbes défectifs. Quid, par exemple, d'éventuelles réformes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

À lire, ou plutôt à survoler, la section du *bon usage* qui leur est consacrée (elle fait quinze pages dans mon édition), j'ai l'impression que chaque verbe ou presque a son histoire.

Il y a des verbes qui sont défectifs par manque de besoin (verbes essentiellement impersonnel, verbes ayant normalement pour sujet des choses ou des animaux, verbes inusités à certains temps à cause de leur signification —  certains verbes ayant intrinsèquement une notion de durée ne vont pas être conjugués au passé simple — , les verbes de la langue populaire vont rarement être conjugué aux formes propres à la langue littéraire, …) et si le besoin surgit pour une raison ou une autre, les formes resurgissent s'ils ne font pas partie aussi de la catégorie suivante.

Puis il y a les verbes à la conjugaison irrégulière dont les formes irrégulières n'ont jamais existé ou sont tombées hors d'usage, et les verbes eux-même presque tombés complètement hors d'usage qui ne survivent que dans quelques expressions consacrées.  Pour ceux là, le moment où ils sont tombés hors d'usage varie beaucoup.

Grevisse liste 33 verbes défectifs.  Certains n'ont pas d'indication historique du tout.  Pour la plupart des autres, la notice ne concerne en rien l'aspect défectif du verbe. Pour les derniers, il se contente de donner quelques formes qui ont été utilisées mais qui ne le sont plus.

> La plupart des verbes défectifs sont condamnés à disparaître ou du moins à ne subsister que dans des locutions toutes faites. Déjà, parmi les formes que la tradition maintient pieusement dans les grammaires, il en est beaucoup que la langue parlée ignore absolument et auxquelles la langue écrite ne conserve qu'artificiellement un certain souffle de vie.

Comment: Je me souviens vaguement d'un dialogue dans *Hygiène de l'assassin* : « Déchoyez ! — Vous ne pouvez pas dire ça : c'est un verbe défectif. »

Comment: "Un verbe ayant intrinsèquement une notion de durée ne va pas être conjugué au passé simple" : le verbe *attendre*, par exemple, se conjugue très bien au passé simple...

Comment: J'ai résumé ce que Grevisse écrivait. Je regarde ce soir où j'ai fait un raccourcit trop important ce faisant.

Comment: @subtenante, il est deux choses; j'ai généralisé un peu trop d'une part, d'autre part quand un verbe est effectivement défectif (il a des formes non usitées) mais de conjugaison suffisamment régulière (et celle des verbes en -dre l'est suffisamment pour ça), les formes non usitées peuvent être régénérée si on en a besoin.

Answer (score 0):

Pourquoi un nouveau verbe ne serait-il pas à l'origine muni de tous ses modes et temps ? Sauf incompatibilité sémantique.

Mais l'usage délaisse certaines formes.

"Je heurte une pierre, l'équilibre me défaut, et je chus" (présent de narration) me semble correct, mais pour le moins devenu inusuel. Contrairement à "déchoir" et "échoir", "choir" ne subsiste plus guère qu'au futur, grâce à Perrault : " ... et la bobinette cherra".

Inversement, l'usage consacre des formes au fond aberrantes pour les mots courants ; "aller" a trois racines latines distinctes : je vais, j'irai, je suis allé".

Le caractère défectif ne concerne pas que les verbes : impossible de mettre au féminin "il est sot et fat" - le second défaut n'est pourtant pas que masculin ?

Comment: [**fate**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fat) se dit, bien qu'il soit moins usité que le masculin

Comment: Le Littré dit explicitement - sans explication - que fat n'a pas de féminin. Avez-vous une autre source ? Merci. mark thorin

Comment: Le TLF, voir lien dans mon commentaire précédent