# Comment traduire « I don't care » ou « That does not concern me » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, registre-familier, registre-soutenu

Souvent, j'ai le sentiment que je me suis trompé de registre pour ces phrases.

Il y a trois traductions que je connais :

1. Je me soucie de cette situation. (courant : *I care about this situation* / *This is my concern*.)
2. Je ne me soucie pas de cette situation. (courant : *I am not concerned with that*.)
3. Je m'en fous. (familier : *I really don't care about that*.)

Donc, les questions :

1. Est-ce que les registres ci-dessus sont corrects  ?
2. Quelle est la traduction en registre soutenu ?
3. Quelle est la traduction de « *I don't care* » en registre familier ?

Answer (score 12):

Dans un registre familier :

- « *I don't care* » (Des traductions que j'estime être dans l'ordre du moins familier au plus familier :)

  > « je m'en fiche », « Je m'en fous », « J'en ai rien à foutre »  ou « Rien à battre »
- « *I am not concerned with that* »

  > « Ce n'est pas mes oignons »

Dans un registre plus soutenu :

- « *I don't care* »

  > « Cela m'importe peu »
- « *I am not concerned with that* »

  > « Cela ne me concerne pas », « Cela ne me regarde pas »

Comment: @Evpok merci pour la mise en forme ;) Il y a plusieurs de mes réponses qui ont été modifiées, je vais faire des efforts !

Comment: Pas de problème, regarde du coté de http://users.numericable.be/denis.liegeois//kbdfrac.htm pour les guillemets français

Comment: Pour les guillemets francais (sous Windows), j'ai tendance à préférer [ALT + 0171] et [ALT + 0187]

Comment: "J'en ai rien à foutre" and "Rien à battre" are much too vulgar to translate "I don't care". Even "Je m'en fous" is borderline.

Answer (score 9):

Les trois phrases sont correctes, mais je dirais que la première phrase n'est probablement pas beaucoup utilisée et met plus l'accent sur le fait que le locuteur est inquiet à cause de la situation, et pas tellement qu'elle l'intéresse.

Dans la plupart des cas de figure, on aura tendance à mettre l'emphase sur la situation en l'utilisant comme sujet :

- La situation m'inquiète.
- La situation m'intéresse.
- La situation me préoccupe. (plus soutenu)
- La situation m'interpelle. (plus soutenu)
- La situation ne m'intéresse pas.

Une bonne traduction de « I don't care. » sans sombrer dans le vulgaire *je m'en fous* serait d'ailleurs *ça ne m'intéresse pas*. (Les variantes de *je m'en fous* : *je m'en moque*, *je m'en fiche*, *je m'en tape*, *je m'en balance* ne sont pas plus élégantes les unes que les autres).

Plus soutenu, il y a encore :

- Ça me laisse froid.
- Ça me laisse de glace.
- Ça me laisse de marbre.
- Ça me laisse de (truc froid quelconque).

Comme sommet dans le language soutenu, je recommande le verbe [défectif](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/953) [chaloir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaloir) :

- Peu me chaut.

Comment: "*Peu me chaut*" une expression qui n'attire plus le chaland depuis des décennies !

Answer (score 7):

1. Pour 1. et 2., je dirais plutôt *je m'en soucie* et [*je ne m'en soucie pas*](http://www.atatheatre.com/saynetes2/Lamoureux.htm), qui sont bien du registre courant.
2. Pour le registre soutenu, au choix

   - « Cela ne m'importe pas/peu/guère »
   - « Peu me chaut » (vieilli)
   - « Peu importe » qui est entre courant et soutenu
3. « Je m'en fous » est un bon exemple pour le registre familier, avec comme variantes « je m'en fous/tape/cogne/balance », « (j'en ai) rien à cirer/à foutre/à fiche/à battre/à taper » et mon cher « je m'en tamponne le coquillard »

De manière générale les frontières sont assez ténues entre courant et soutenu.

Comment: J'ai jamais compris d'où venait « je m'en fiche », et encore moins le grammaticalement douteux « rien à fiche ».

Comment: @Stéphane https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/ficher#.C3.89tymologie

Comment: Merci. Ça n'a donc aucun sens, et je suis content de le savoir. Maintenant je saurai pourquoi j'évite de l'utiliser.

Answer (score 7):

Les phrases que tu as citées sont correctes, et leur registre aussi, mais :

- *Je m'en fous*, en plus d'être familier, est péjoratif. C'est plus proche de *I don't give a f-* que de *I don't care*.
- *Je ne me soucie pas de cette situation* se comprend très bien, mais sonne inhabituel.

Voici ce que je te propose (liste non exhaustive) :

- Registre soutenu

  > (Cela) ne me concerne pas
  >   (Cela) ne me soucie pas
  >   Je ne suis pas concerné par (ceci)
  >   Je ne suis pas parti prenant en (ceci)
  >   Qu'importe (cela)
- Registre courant (mais toutefois très correct, utilisable même en des cas formels)

  > (Cela) n'est pas mon affaire
  >   (Cela) ne m'intéresse pas (*attention: cette phrase peut avoir deux sens: être intéressé signifie être concerné, mais aussi porter un intérêt*)
  >   (Cela) m'est égal
  >   Peu importe (cela)
- Registre familier

  > Je m'en fous (*généralement péjoratif, attention*)
  >   Je m'en fiche (*généralement péjoratif, attention*)
  >   (Ça) m'est égal
  >   (Ça) ne changera pas ma vie(*généralement péjoratif, attention*)

Plus toutes les formules du registre courant vues plus haut, avec *Ça* au lieu et place de *Cela* :

- Argot

  > Je m'en tape
  >   Je m'en contrefous
  >   Je m'en cogne
  >   Je n'en ai rien à battre

Voire plus imagé encore. On peut même être créatif<sup>(*)</sup>.

<sup>(*)On m'a dit un jour: *je m'en tape le gland contre le crépi*. C'était fort peu classe, mais ceci dit c'était très clair même sans jamais l'avoir entendu avant.</sup>

Comment: Je sens que pas grand-monde ne va s'aventurer trop loin dans le _voire plus imagé encore_ :-)

Comment: Puisqu'on peut être plus créatif... _Je m'en coiffe les poils de barbe avec la toute dernière énergie._

Comment: Et c'est on ne peut plus clair :) Etonnant, non ?

Comment: Il ne faudrait pas croire pour autant que la formule _je m'en + verbe_ peut être déclinée à toutes les sauces. _Je m'en vais complètement_, par exemple, passe mal.

Comment: @Joubarc Variante de *J'en ai les sourcils qui frémissent* ?

Comment: @Joubarc Non, et c'est difficile de déterminer ce qui passera ou pas... Il faudra que j'essaie *Je m'en inspire largement* en situation pour voir :)

Comment: Sadique :-) Note, tu pourrais au moins laisser un indice: _Je m'en inspire comme de ma première chemise_

Answer (score 5):

Expressions très utilisées pour « *I don't care* » en langage courant :

- « je n'en ai rien à faire »
- légèrement plus soutenu mais toujours assez neutre « cela m'est égal », contracté en « ça m'est égal »

Answer (score 5):

Une expression familière et imagée:

> Ça me fait une belle jambe.

Answer (score 4):

1. Les registres ci-dessus sont corrects mais la traduction est peut-être peu naturelle en fonction du contexte.
2. Une des traductions que je vois en registre soutenu pourrait être « cela ne me soucie guère » ou « cela ne me soucie pas ». Peu de différence donc avec le registre courant et encore une fois différent selon le contexte.
3. « Je m'en fous » est bien, mais il existe bien évidemment beaucoup de traductions possibles et plus ou moins vulgaires.

Comment: Jamais entendu _cela ne me soucie pas/guère_, c'est un peu bizarre comme tournure de phrase, non?

Comment: Le Wikitionnaire ne liste qu'une seule forme pour [soucier](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/soucier), et elle est réflexive (se soucier).

Comment: @Joubarc Ah, *cela ne me soucie pas/guère*, je l'entends quelquefois

Answer (score 4):

Pour exprimer son manque d'intérêt, on peut dire aussi qu'on s'en moque, souvent « comme de sa première chemise » d'ailleurs mais la comparaison est parfois nettement plus vulgaire. On peut aussi remplacer s'en moquer par une série d'autres expressions déjà citées (s'en foutre, s'en taper, ...).

Un peu en marge de la question, le « I care »  utilisé pour exprimer sa sympathie se rend mieux avec des formules comme « je compatis » impliquant plus la personne subissant la situation que la situation elle-même.

Comment: Ce n'est pas parce que toutes les autres réponses ont laissé cet aspect-là de côté qu'il était en marge de la question, au contraire.

Comment: La question est essentiellement tournée vers les formes négatives. Si j'ai déjà rencontré des gens exprimant une sympathie qu'ils ne ressentaient visiblement pas, je n'ai pas encore rencontré quelqu'un exprimant son absence de sympathie aussi brutalement.

Answer (score 4):

Une expression courante qui exprime la même idée est **« c'est pas mon problème »**. De nombreux étrangers venant vivre en France trouvent d'ailleurs que c'est [une attitude très (trop) française](http://myfrenchlife.org/2011/08/25/pros-and-cons-of-life-in-france/) :

> For example, here are some of my biggest French pet peeves:
>   [...]
>   • *“C’est pas mon problème”.*  I’m gonna make it your problem, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

en complément de ce qui a déjà été dit :

1) en langage formel/soutenu : Dans le cas où l'on est sollicité pour donner son avis ou bien pour intervenir et prendre partie répondre : « Ce n'est pas de mon ressort », ne signifie pas qu'on ne se sent pas concerné dans le sens affectif du mot *concern* mais qu'on n'est pas concerné dans le sens qu'on estime ne pas être la bonne personne à qui s'adresser, qu'on n'a pas de compte à rendre ou pas la compétence ou la ressource nécessaire pour répondre.

2) en langage familier, catégorique et indélicat : j'en ai rien à battre, rien à branler, rien à carrer, rien à braire, rien à traire, ou bien encore je m'en contrefous comme de ma dernière chaussette

3) en langage familier, indécent, cru, vulgaire, insultant mais si imagé que c'est à mourir de rire sous cape ou bien hors situation, lorsqu'on la relate : je m'en branle les cacahuètes, je m'en tamponne le coquillard (quoique l'expression soit détournée de son sens premier (vu ici : http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/s-en-battre-l-oeil-s-en-tamponner-le-coquillard.php), je m'en vaseline le coccyx, je m'en poignarde le cul avec un diot (expression locale en Savoie),