# Synonymes de l'expression "ça m’est égal"

Tags: vocabulaire

Quelle est la différence entre les expressions suivantes ? Parmi les expressions suivantes, lesquelles sont polies et lesquelles sont obscènes ? Je serai reconnaissant si vous ajoutez de nouvelles expressions synonymes à cette liste.

- ça m'est égal
- je m'en fiche
- je m'en fous
- je m'en moque
- peu m'importe
- je m'en tape

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/970/comment-traduire-i-dont-care-ou-that-does-not-concern-me

Comment: J'avais un professeur de maths qui aimait dire "ça m'est équilatéral". C'était très idiolectique et même un peu pédant, mais assez drôle.

Comment: Une petite de Chirac: "Cela m'en touche une sans faire bouger l'autre"

Comment: Val *[s'en branlait](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xawt33)* de passer à la radio, un branleur qui a fini directeur de France Inter.  *Peu me chaut*. Son collègue, qui a pris le titre du morceau au sens litteral, a lui fini derrière les barreaux. Bon ça non plus *j'en n'ai cure*, comme on dit au presbytère.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les formes problématiques du point de vue usage sont examinée en dernier.

**I** *registre non vulgaire*

- **ça m'est égal** (*registre courant, factuel*)
- **peu m'importe** (*registre courant,  factuel*)
- **je m'en moque** (*registre courant, plus ou moins méprisant*)
- **je m'en fiche** (euphémisme qui rappelle « s'en foutre » ; voir [WR, Lougarou](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sen-ficher-sen-foutre.115690/) : « S'en foutre est une expression vulgaire, souvent employée dans le langage parlé, mais qui n'est pas recommandable pour les jeunes filles "bien élevées". S'en ficher (ou s'en fiche) est plus acceptable; l'excellent dictionnaire "Le Petit Robert" dit clairement: ficher s'emploie par euphémisme à la place de foutre. » ; registre courant, plus ou moins méprisant*)

*Autres expressions*

- ça n'a pas d'importance (pour moi)
- ça m'est indifférent
- je n'en ai rien à faire

---

**II** *Registre vulgaire (plus ou moins)*

Des deux formes qui restent il n'y en a aucune d'obscène. Il y en deux de familières mais qui sont trouvées par nombre d'utilisateur toujours vulgaires ; « s'en taper » n'est que populaire d'après le TLFi.

Lorsque les gens utilisent « foutre », il ne sont pas conscient qu'il s'agit d'un mot qui est très  vulgaire ; la raison est l'usage : il n'est plus utilisé pour l'acte de copulation, et il a été remplacé par d'autres dans les emplois vulgaires. Les seuls à devenir conscient de cette idée sont ceux qui ont été assez curieux pour consulter des dictionnaires et lire une certaine littérature passée d'âge.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foutre)) A.− Trivial. Posséder charnellement. Synon. baiser (vulg.), enculer (trivial).La femme (...) est en rut et veut être foutue. Le beau mérite! (Baudel., Cœur nu,1867, p. 643).Je suis ce soir, au chemin de fer, à côté d'un ouvrier complètement saoul, qui répète à tout moment : « Non, je ne la foutrais pas, quand on me donnerait tout Paris... oui, tout Paris, non, je ne la foutrais pas! » (Goncourt, Journal,1872, p. 900).

Dans le cas de « taper » (« s'en taper » ) la notion même d'obscènité est non seulement impeceptible mais totalement absente parce que même le monde instruit ne sait pas exactement d'où provient cette expression. On suppose qu'il pourrait s'agir   « s'en taper le cul par terre », qui n'est que vulgaire ; cependant, tout aussi bien ce pourrait être l'expression plus complète qui provient de la courte ; dans ce cas aussi les gens ne savent pas vraiment ce que disent les mots qu'ils utilisent : ils ont seulement internalisé un contexte d'utilisation et plus ou moins un registre, et le reste, c'est du son. Donc, le sens de copuler avec quelqu'un (les deux sexes), dans l'esprit des gens,  est loin d'être insinué. Cette forme est à rapprocher, pour ce qui est du manque de transparence, de « se taper », dont la signification vulgaire est « Se priver (de quelque chose); se passer (de quelque chose) » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper)) ; on n'a aucune idée qu'il puisse exister une relation avec « se taper » posséder charnellement), ni même de comment il pourrait y en avoir une.

> ([WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sen-taper-vulgaire.3328835/))
> On dit « s'en taper le cul par terre »

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_taper)) **s’en taper**
> (Familier) Se désintéresser ou être totalement indifférent de la chose ou personne en question.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper)) 3. Pop., vulg. [Le compl. désigne une pers.] Posséder charnellement, faire l'amour avec. Synon. pop., vulg. s'envoyer.Se taper un mec, une gonzesse. J'aimais mieux repasser par l'école que de me taper la Gwendoline (Céline, Mort à crédit, 1936, p. 260).

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper) ne fait aucune référence à une expression plus complète.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper)) 2. S'en taper.Se moquer, ne pas faire cas de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un. Synon. pop. s'en balancer, s'en foutre.Le surlendemain, qu'est-ce que nous n'entendîmes pas au rapport au sujet des 250 000 cartouches brûlées!... Nous, on s'en tapait (Cendrars, Main coupée, 1946, p. 71).[Un ouvrier à ses camarades] − La politique, on s'en tape (Vialar, Fins dern., 1953, p. 122).

*Autres expressions*

Dans des registres similaires, c'est à dire plus ou moins vulgaires, on trouve les formes suivantes.

- s'en taper/battre le coquillard
- s'en tamponner le oquillard
- s'en torcher (le cul)
- s'en battre les couilles
- s'en battre l'œil (*apparemment un euphémisme*)
- s'en balancer
- s'en foutre comme de [ses premières chaussettes]/…
- s'en battre les flancs
- n'en avoir rien à foutre