# Why does the verb « clore » have no Imparfait form?

Tags: conjugaison, verbes-défectifs

When looking at conjugation lists online (reverso, leconjugeur), the verb « clore » doesn't have any listed forms for the vous, nous (in the present), imparfait or passé simple. Can anyone suggest any reasons why « clore » is not used for any of these contexts such that it has no conjugation for them and for example, if I had written (from my understanding this verb is really on used in novels and textbooks) « vous closez » would that be understandable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Vous **closez** la discussion* would raise eyebrows and smell the anglicism (although present in the 2006 Bescherelle edition).

The verb *[clore](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clore#fr)* lost a lot of its [old conjugated forms](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/tableaux-de-conjugaison/forclore) because they clashed with the ones of the verb *clouer* (The expected historical form would have been *Vous **clouez/cloez/cluez** la discussion*). As Un francophone wrote, *clôturer* and *fermer* are common enough substitutes for it.

See also: [« Système fermé » contre « système clos »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33821)

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave to someone else the *why* question for the case of *clore*, it needs sources that I don't have. A more general answer about the history of defective verbs has been given [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/953/quand-et-comment-sont-apparus-les-verbes-d%c3%a9fectifs).

*closez* seems regular enough to me that it could be used if the need arose, but with *fermer* and *clôturer* available, providing the more common meanings of *clore* and having a regular conjugation, that will probably not happen.

Answer (score 2):

@Unfrancophone has given the right answer, i.e. it is a defective verb and I doubt another reason then the ones he's already given, [historical](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/961/358) and [semantic proximity](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50523/358) with *clôturer*, could be found.

Your question is a good one and not a new one as [Littré points out](https://www.littre.org/definition/clore):

> Des grammairiens se sont plaints qu'on laissât sans raison tomber en désuétude plusieurs formes du verbe clore. Pourquoi en effet ne dirait-on pas : nous closons, vous closez ; l'imparfait, je closais ; le prétérit défini, je closis, et l'imparfait du subjonctif, je closisse ? Ces formes n'ont rien de rude ni d'étrange, et il serait bon que l'usage ne les abandonnât pas.

That being said, Grevisse (*Le bon usage*, §701, 10th edition) gives the following examples found in literature of the use of *clore* in the *passé simple*:

> - Le baron se penchât se pencha davantage sur le visage, closit lui même les paupières. (Henri Béraud, *Le bois du templier perdu*, 1926)
> - Il a fallu (..) qu'on la closit de trois fils barbelés.(Maurice Bedel, *Géographie de mille hectares*, 1937).

We can note as well that the derivatives of *clore* are defective too, and they vary in their existing forms. [*Éclore*](https://www.littre.org/definition/%C3%A9clore) can be used in all forms of the *présent de l'indicatif* but is not supposed to be used in the *passé simple*, nevertheless we can read this sentence in *Soto* by [Philippe Djia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Djian)n (published in 1993):

> Des cloisons disparurent, des fenêtres s'ouvrirent sur le toit, une énorme baie pulvérisa le mur au sud-ouest et une véranda éclosit au sud-est.

Answer (score 0):

C’est un verbe défectif. Il n’existe pas toutes les formes et à toutes les personnes.